# How can I add a column in sql query from nested join?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Access and having three tables: `Category`, `Topic` and `Post`.  What I am trying to achieve is to include in the result the date of the last post creation.

`Post` table has a `CreatedOn` column.

Currently my query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    category.id,
    category.CategoryName,
    category.Description,
    count(tp.topic.id) AS NumberOfTopics,
    Sum(numofposts) AS NumberOfPosts
FROM category
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        topic.id,
        topic.categoryId,
        count(post.id) AS numofposts
    FROM
        topic
        LEFT JOIN post ON topic.id = post.topicId 
    GROUP BY topic.id, topic.categoryId
) AS TP ON category.id=TP.categoryid
GROUP BY category.id, category.CategoryName, category.Description;
```

My best attempt (in my opinion) was to extend a query in a following way:

```
SELECT
    category.id,
    category.CategoryName,
    category.Description,
    COUNT(topic.id) AS NumberOfTopics,
    sum(numofposts) AS NumberOfPosts,
    "DUMMY" AS last
FROM category
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        topic.id,
        COUNT(ps.id) AS numofposts,
        topic.categoryId 
    FROM topic
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            id,
            CreatedOn,
            topicId
        FROM post
        ORDER BY post.CreatedOn DESC
    ) AS ps ON topic.id = ps.topicId
    GROUP BY topic.id, topic.categoryId
)  AS TP ON category.id=TP.categoryid
GROUP BY category.id, category.CategoryName, category.Description;
```

Unfortunately I've tried a many different ways to get it, but I am still unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using inline `SELECT` clauses:

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.CategoryName,
    c.Description,
    (SELECT count(t.id)
     FROM topic t
     WHERE t.categoryId = c.id
    ) AS NumberOfTopics,
    (SELECT count(p.id)
     FROM post p
     JOIN topic t ON p.topicId = t.id
     WHERE t.categoryId = c.id
    ) AS NumberOfPosts,
    (SELECT max(p.createdOn) FROM post p
     JOIN topic t ON p.topicId = t.id
     WHERE t.categoryId = c.id
    ) AS LastPostDate
FROM category c;
```

This may not be the most efficient query, but produces the right results.

See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/165d1/2 for a demo.

Comment: That's fantastic answer Thank you! Could you please tell me if I should follow the same pattern if I would like to add one more value from that post ie. for example CreatedBy which is in post for which that createdOn belongs.